# script file is not getting executed on target machine using ansible script module

Tags: ansible-playbook

script file is not getting executed on target machine using ansible script module.

I have written a script file on control-node wants that to copy it on target machine and then from there i wants to run the script file using ansible script module.

```
playbook:
---
- name: execute script file on target
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: copy script file
      copy:
        src: /home/ansibleuser/practice-ansible/pre-check.sh
        dest: /home/ansibleuser/
        mode: 0777
    - name: execute the script on destination servers
      script:
        cmd: /home/ansibleuser/pre-check.sh
      args:
       removes: /home/ansibleuser/pre-check.sh
      register: output
```

```
Error:
"changed": false,
    "msg": "Could not find or access '/home/ansibleuser/pre-check.sh' on the Ansible Controller.
If you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - you might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems pretty clear. The [`script` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html) works by first (a) copying the mentioned script from the control host (your local system) to the remote system and then (b) running it.

You don't need your `copy` task. You just need to fix the path in the `script` module:

```
- name: execute script file on target
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: execute the script on destination servers
      script:
        cmd: /home/ansibleuser/practice-ansible/pre-check.sh
      register: output
```